# Unable to connect mysql - web application

Tags: mysql, linux, database, web

Ihello, i am using webmin to administer my linux server. I have a problem with MySQL, I created a user by assigning rights. But I can't log in with my web app.

[database permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOSZ0.png)

[user permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qq7Y.png)

Application error: TNG is not communicating with your database. Please check your database settings and try again. Settings can be found under Admin/Setup/General Settings/Database, or at the top of your config.php file.

bind-addres = 0.0.0.0

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the database on a different server from the web front end?

Comment: Please post TEXT if your images contain only text....

Comment: The front end and database are same server. I changed the image to text. Thanks

Comment: I'am not probleme in root user.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem ...
i launch this command and it's work :

```
ALTER USER '...'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```